# Plotting difference between two Half Normal Distributions

Tags: plotting, distributions

I am new to Mathematica, and this question may reflect that.

I am trying to plot the probability density function of a random variable which equals the difference between two independent random variables that are Half Normal distributed.

Can someone help me out?

Comment: If I made the wrong changes to your question, please change it back.

Comment: Should be able to do `PDF[TransformedDistribution[
  x - y, {x \[Distributed] HalfNormalDistribution[\[Theta]], 
   y \[Distributed] HalfNormalDistribution[\[Theta]]}], z]`, but it's taking a long time and returning unevaluated.

Comment: @march:  `PDF` and `CDF` return unevaluated (even with values assigned to $\theta$) but `Expectation` and `RandomVariate` work on the `TransformedDistribution`.  Maybe one needs to brute force the integration of the joint probability distribution or take a large random sample and use `SmoothKernelDistribution`.

Comment: @JimBaldwin. I wasn't aware of `SmoothKernelDistribution`. It ends up kind of nice: plotting the pdf of `SmoothKernelDistribution@RandomVariate[dist /. \[Theta] -> 1, {1000000}]` looks pretty good. I feel like an answer is in order there.

Comment: @JimBaldwin : "...Maybe one needs to brute force the integration of the joint probability distribution..." - that's gonna be ugly...

Comment: @ciao.  Challenge accepted.

Comment: @JimBaldwin +1 applied ...

Answer (score 9):

Hmmm. Maybe it's not so hard (with *Mathematica*) after all.  If the two independent and identically distributed half-normal random variables are labeled $u$ and $v$, then the difference is $d=u-v$.  If we can find the CDF of $d$, then we can differentiate to get the density of $d$.

Suppose $d_0 \ge 0$.  Then

$$Pr(d\le d_0)=Pr(u-v\le d_0)=\int_0^\infty{\int_0^{d_0+u}(\frac{2 \theta  e^{-\frac{\theta ^2 v^2}{\pi }}}{\pi })(\frac{2 \theta  e^{-\frac{\theta ^2 u^2}{\pi }}}{\pi })}dv du$$

So we can get the density with

```
D[Integrate[PDF[HalfNormalDistribution[θ], u] PDF[HalfNormalDistribution[θ], v],
  {u, 0, ∞}, {v, 0, d + u}, Assumptions -> {θ > 0, d >= 0}], d]

(* (Sqrt[2] E^(-((d^2 θ^2)/(2 π))) θ Erfc[(d θ)/Sqrt[2 π]])/π *)
```

While the next step with $d_0<0$ can be made more justifiably, a bit of handwaving notes that the distribution is symmetric about 0 when the two half-normal distributions have the same parameter.  That results in the density function of the difference being

```
(Sqrt[2] E^(-((d^2 θ^2)/(2 π))) θ (1 + Erf[(Abs[d] θ)/Sqrt[2 π]]))/π
```

A plot of this function against a huge random sample from the same distribution does not suggest the result is wrong.  So borrowing from @march we have the following:

```
dist = TransformedDistribution[x - y, {x \[Distributed] HalfNormalDistribution[θ], 
 y \[Distributed] HalfNormalDistribution[θ]}]
sample = RandomVariate[dist /. θ -> 1, {1000000}];
f[z_] = PDF[SmoothKernelDistribution[sample, {"Adaptive", Automatic, Automatic}], z];
Plot[{(Sqrt[2] E^(-(d^2/(2 π))) Erfc[Abs[d]/Sqrt[2 π]])/π, f[d]}, {d, -5, 5},
  PlotStyle -> {{Green, Thickness[0.015]}, Blue}]
```

[image: probability density function of difference of two half-normals]

**UPDATE**

I offer the following without proof for the case where the half-normal parameters differ.

```
g12[a_, b_] := (D[Integrate[PDF[HalfNormalDistribution[a], u] PDF[HalfNormalDistribution[b], v],{u, 0, ∞}, {v, 0, d + u}, Assumptions -> {a > 0, b > 0, d >= 0}], d]) /. d -> Abs[d]
g[a_, b_] = Piecewise[{{g12[a, b], d <= 0}, {g12[b, a], d > 0}}]

θ1 = 4;
θ2 = 0.75;
dist = TransformedDistribution[
  x - y, {x \[Distributed] HalfNormalDistribution[θ1], 
  y \[Distributed] HalfNormalDistribution[θ2]}]
sample = RandomVariate[dist, {1000000}];
f[z_] = PDF[SmoothKernelDistribution[sample, {"Adaptive", Automatic, Automatic}], z];
Plot[{g[θ1, θ2], f[d]}, {d, -5, 5}, 
  PlotStyle -> {{Green, Thickness[0.015]}, Blue}, PlotRange -> All]
```

[image: Unequal half-normal parameters]

So in general the density function when the half-normal paramaters are not equal is given by

[image: Density function for unequal parameters]

Comment: Aren't your two expressions for positive and negative `d` the same?

Comment: @Eckhard.  I don't think so.  The numerators in the `Erfc` function differ in that one has $\theta1$ and the other has $\theta2$.

Comment: Indeed. Hasty reading on my part.

Comment: @Eckhard.  Review comments are always welcome.  I promise that I'll mess something up real soon.

Answer (score 6):

To get the distribution, do

```
dist = TransformedDistribution[x - y, {x \[Distributed] HalfNormalDistribution[θ], y \[Distributed] HalfNormalDistribution[θ]}]
```

(Note: `\[Distributed]` can be quickly entered in *Mathematica* using <kbd>Esc</kbd>+<kbd>dist</kbd>+<kbd>Esc</kbd>.)

Ideally, we'd like to do

```
PDF[dist, z]
```

to get the pdf as a function of `z`, but this returns unevaluated, even in the case where you specify a value for `θ`.

For that reason, we take a numerical approach by generating a pseudo-random sample from the distribution and using `SmoothKernelDistribution` (as suggested by [JimBaldwin](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/19758/jim-baldwin) in a comment under the OP) to generate a numerical approximation of the pdf, as follows.

```
sample = RandomVariate[dist /. θ -> 1, {1000000}];
f[z_] = PDF[SmoothKernelDistribution[sample], z];
Plot[f[z], {z, -5, 5}]
```

[image]

As suggested by a comment by the OP below, for different parameters, just do

```
dist = TransformedDistribution[x - y, {x \[Distributed] HalfNormalDistribution[θ1], y \[Distributed] HalfNormalDistribution[θ2]}];
```

and then

```
sample = RandomVariate[dist /. {\[Theta]1 -> 4, \[Theta]2 -> 0.75}, {1000000}];
f[z_] = PDF[SmoothKernelDistribution[sample], z];
Plot[f[z], {z, -5, 5}]
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you, March. In the case you specify, the random variables have the same theta. Can you show the case where theta can be different?

I note that in "dist", theta is identical, and that in your sampling, you specify "theta arrow 1". I suspect that if I add subscripts to the thetas, and add another "theta arrow", for example "theta arrow 0.5", I get the answer I am looking for, but I have been unable to find the correct syntax. So your help is much appreciated.